# Join Issue - How to bring back only 1 outer join per row

Tags: join

I don't think my title explained it very well :)

I have a query that has quite a few joins on it.

```
SELECT
sof_slot_games.launch_date,
sof_slot_games.game_name,
sof_reviews.review_content,
sof_slot_games.slot_game_id,
sof_slot_game_details.no_of_reels,
sof_slot_game_details.paylines,
sof_reviews.reg_timestamp,
sof_developers.developer_name,
sof_slot_games.game_slug,
sof_slot_game_images.game_image
FROM
sof_reviews
Inner Join sof_slot_games ON sof_slot_games.slot_game_id = sof_reviews.slot_game_id
Inner Join sof_slot_game_details ON sof_slot_games.slot_game_id = sof_slot_game_details.slot_game_id
Inner Join sof_developers ON sof_slot_games.developer_id = sof_developers.developer_id
left outer Join sof_slot_game_images ON sof_reviews.slot_game_id = sof_slot_game_images.slot_game_id
WHERE
sof_slot_game_images.image_type_id =  '3'
ORDER BY
sof_slot_games.launch_date DESC
limit 0,20
```

The problem is that I want to return just 1 game_image per row. The games themselves are basically the most recent 20 games by launch_date.  But if I join with the game_image (type=3), then it will bring back multiple rows for the same game if that game has multiple images.

I want to really just pick the most recent 20 games and then pull back the 1st image for each.  This is to go into an RSS Feed for the top 20 games which is why I want to do it this way (in case anyone is wondering) :)

I've been trying to figure this out... I know I have done it before, but my brain is not reminding me what I did :)

Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas?  The outer join in the top portion is what the problem is... I thought that would join the top 20 with a relevant image from the datatable, but that's not quite how it is working.

Comment: I figured it out.  I added a subquery in the select statement to select from images based upon the image type with a limit of 1.  That got me what I needed. thanks.